# Sort a column with string format dd/MM/yyyy in SQLite (Android)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I have an SQLite database in an Android project with a Date column that stores the date-time as String in **dd-mm-yyyy HH-mm-ss** format. I need to sort it based on the descending order of the date. 
Or, convert it to the standard **yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss** format and then sort it.

The general ORDER BY DATETIME(coulmn_name) doesnt work.

**NOTE:**

This is not a duplicate question, other answers advice to change the database schema (Which is not possible, because I have data stored already)

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest an alternative approach to the one you are taking. I personally ran into the same issue and solved it by not using a string date at all.

Instead i converted the date to epoch milliseconds ie unix timestamp and saved that. Then a sort is a simple order by the timestamp.

You can use the following approach:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

Date currentDate = sdf.parse(yourdatestring);

//Get the calendar in the time zone you need, generally it works off the bat with the default time zone
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("yourtz"));

cal.setTime(currentDate);

//Get the milliseconds since epoch time
long millis = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

You can save this timestamp and easily sort it. It'll be more accurate and easy to use than a string and potentially gives you the ability to handle different time zones.

You can retrieve the date by setting this timestamp directly in the calendar and getting a date from it

```
cal.setTimeInMillis(timestamp).getTime();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i guess, it's also a lot more performant than storing a date in a string. Especially for sorting and/or creating an index on said column.

Comment: Does it follow from the question that database modification is unwelcome?

Comment: He can always add a column and not modify the same one... Ie not mess up the data, just add to it, schema change yes... Better in the long run yes... Does his data need to be dropped, no.  I believe adding a null or bigint column and putting the dates already stored in this format will be the best alternative for optimal processing.  In short.. keep doing what you are doing but add the time stamp to all existing and new data sets

Comment: @Kushan Great idea. But since I have multiple date columns in several tables it might not be feasible. Nevertheless, I'll try it out!